# Youtube Data API v3, Receiving 403 after creating multiple streams

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api, youtube-data-api

I am using the Youtube Data API to create live broadcasts programatically. Within the hour, I am able to create around 5-6 streams at which point I will begin to receive 403 `insufficientLivePermissions` error. If I wait another 30 minutes and try again, it allows me to make 2 more broadcasts but will then return 403s again.

I checked to see if my access token was expired, but it works when making listing requests. It almost seems to be that I am getting rate limited. When I check my Youtube account however, all indicators are in green so I don't believe I am abusing their API.

This is the response from the YouTube Data v3 API:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "youtube.liveBroadcast",
        "reason": "insufficientLivePermissions",
        "message": "Request is not authorized",
        "extendedHelp": "https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert#auth_required"
      }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request is not authorized"
  }
}
```

I am also not hitting anywhere near the Quota limits for the API. Any ideas to why the 403 `insufficientLivePermissions` would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue but the answer below looks like it's not what I need ... because everything is setup and works fine except when I exceed some quota ... it looks like the user is limited to a specific number of liveBroadcast create operations per hour.

Comment: hey @Giacoman,  I am also getting this issue. please tell me if You know the answer

Comment: @Basha We were getting rate limited by Youtube. From the research we have done, Youtube rate limits all accounts to creating 8-10 broadcasts per 24 hours. Unfortunately, this is not documented anywhere by Youtube.

Comment: @Giacoman, How can we overcome this issue?. if it not possible with free of cost , then possible with any amount?

Comment: @Basha We didn't try paying as we were well below all the limits. Youtube Support wasn't too helpful either. We are currently trying out Red5Pro.

Comment: Thank you @Ulises Giacoman. want to connect through Hangouts , ramjan.basha46@gmail.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue means that you actually created too many live streams : 
if you go to https://www.youtube.com/my_live_events?action_create_live_event=1 and try to create a new livestream you will see :

**You are creating too many live streams. Please wait a while before creating further streams.**

I think the maximum is set to 6 to 7 streams per 24 hours.

ps : It's really **not related** to the issue in the documentation
(missing scopes)

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/errors#liveBroadcasts_youtube.liveBroadcasts.insert), the error `insufficientLivePermissions` means that the request is not authorized to create the live broadcast.

First, try to use the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl` together with `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube` and check if the error 403 will gone.

If not, then I suggest you to check this [YouTube Live Streaming API - Understanding Broadcasts and Streams](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/broadcasts-and-streams) to understand more how the broadcast work.

According to this guide, the **stream** enables you to transmit audio-video content to YouTube, and it defines the settings for how you stream your content to YouTube. The same stream can be bound to up to **three** live broadcasts.

So if you want to create many live broadcast, this guide [Use one stream to create simultaneous broadcasts](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/broadcasts-and-streams#simultaneous_broadcasts) can help you to do it.